# Running VBA code on Word documents that do not have Macros

Tags: c#, vba, dynamic, ms-word

I have looked all over to try and find an example of C# code that calls VBA code to run on a word document.

I am looking for a way to take dynamically generated VBA code and using it on a template copy.

Comment: On of the key guidelines for posting here is demonstrating what you've already tried. If you don't want this to get closed you should post a sample or something you've tried.

Comment: What do you mean with "dynamically generated VBA code"? Who creates it where? You can have VBA code either in a macro-enabled template (or document), or in a global template loaded at Word startup. In both cases the Office security model blocks access to the VBA project, if not allowed through Group Policy or by administrative settings. 
Additionally, for a Word developer it is not clear what you want to do in the template copy what need this approach. You can do a lot in add-ins programmed in C#, VB.NET - or VBA in a global template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .NET Interop. It's an optional component of the Microsoft Office install.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx